# Не могу вывести значение элемента массива

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    class My {
        public function __construct () {
            if(isset($_GET['show'])) {
                $this->get($_GET['show']);
            }
            else {
                $this->get('main');
            }
        }
        public function get ($show) {
            if($show == 'main') {
                return array(
                    "text" => "Main Text",
                );
            }
            else {
                return array(
                    "text" => "Etc text",
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $result = new My;
    echo $result["text"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы пишете 
    $result = new My

У класса My вызывается конструктор, внутри коснтруктора идет вызов метода get, он что то там возвращает. Но это не означает возврат чего либо конструктором, то есть у конструктора нет return. Поэтому ваш $result на уровне здравого смысла не может обрабатываться как массив.
P.S. Надеюсь ваш код абстрактный, иначе его бы весь переписать.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы обращаться к объекту как к массиву, класс должен реализовывать интерфейс [ArrayAccess](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127711/)